# Missing spaces in shipping-information

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I added a module that moves billing address to the shipping step. But now I miss some spaces on the billing address in the sidebar of the billing step.

[image]

I'm missing the spaces between firstname and lastname and zipcode and city.
Does anyone know where those spaces should be set normally in the M2 code? I can't find it.

I did find that module-checkout > view > frontend > web > template < shipping-information.html calls for getRegion('ship-to')

I'm working with this module:
[Modified checkout](https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied default.html and added spaces in KnockoutJs to template > address-renderer > default.html by doing this:

```
<!-- ko text: ' ' -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue thanks !

For someone else with the same problem, don't forget to close the **ko** tag has @Sanne suggests

```
<!-- ko text: ' ' --><!-- /ko -->
```

Use the below code for "opc-block-shipping-information"

```
<!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().middlename --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: ' ' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko -->
```